# English and correct grammar usage

Tags: prepositions

Bridge over the river or bridge on the river which is correct grammar usage

Comment: Or *under* or *around* or *into* or *from or *onto* or *through* or... All **grammatically correct**. Why do you think they might not be?

Answer (score 2):

If you ask Vanguard Press, it's "over."  They published the English version of Pierre Boulle's *[Le Pont de la Rivière Kwai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridge_over_the_River_Kwai)* as *The Bridge **over** the River Kwai*.  If you ask David Lean, it's "on."  He directed the film adaptation of Boulle's novel as *[The Bridge **on** the River Kwai](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050212/?ref_=nv_sr_1)*.

Both prepositions are idiomatic in this usage, but both the google on the web and the Ngram viewer show that "over" is favored.